# Change text when logged in

Tags: php, html

I want to change my navigationbar from saying:

```
<a href="register.php" class="nav-item" id="nav-register">Register</a>
<a href="login.php" class="nav-item" id="nav-login">Login</a>
```

To:

```
<div id="nav-login">Signed in as : &nbsp;<strong><?php echo $login_session; ?></strong><a id="nav-register" href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
```

Where `<?php echo $login_session; ?>` is used to get the loged in users username.

I have not much experience with PHP so please explain it easy.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, here's the answer though; https://eval.in/473705.

Comment: no problem ill work alittle more with it and see what i can come up with, thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
<?php if(isset($login_session) && !empty($login_session)){ ?>
    <div id="nav-login">Signed in as : &nbsp;<strong><?php echo $login_session; ?>
    </strong><a id="nav-register" href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <a href="register.php" class="nav-item" id="nav-register">Register</a>
    <a href="login.php" class="nav-item" id="nav-login">Login</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Make sure `$logged_session` is defined and if you using `$_SESSION` variable use `session_start();` before creating/using `$_SESSION` variable

Comment: No need for the `isset`, empty checks that. `That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.`http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php